# stack of local variables

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, pointers

```
void Test2()
{   
    int c=8;
    int b=7;
    int d=9;
    int *a; 

    a = &b;
    a+=sizeof(int); //I supposed that *a should points on variable d after this 

    cout << "b\t" << &b << "\t" << b << endl;
    cout << "a\t" << a  << "\t" << *a << endl;
    cout << "c\t" << &c  << "\t" << c << endl;
    cout << "d\t" << &d  << "\t" << d << endl;
}
```

I supposed that ***a** should points on variable **d** because **b** and **d** (as I thought) lie nearby in the stack of local variables. But *a points on another address so ***a**!=**d** 
My question is why so? Is it the feature of Visual Studio 2010 or something else?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, not a feature. There is *nothing* in standard C++ which mandates anything like this, in fact compilers are free to do what they see best and you are forbidden from relying on such things. In practice compilers might decide at any point (even a seemingly unrelated change further away) to place things differently which would break your assumption.

Comment: And the comparison you used (`*a != d`) is flawed as they could be equal by chance. `a != &d` would be a better choice.

Comment: I won't make a full answer, as people have already covered the important parts, but it is also worth noting that in most implementations the stack actually grows the other direction, so even if you had done it correctly and got away with the undefined behavior, you would end up pointing at `c`, not at `d`. I only tested this with `g++` on Linux, but I believe it is the case on most systems.

Comment: @Flexo Hmm. *a = b = 7 != d, because d= 9. 
Anyway I put all values and addresses to be sure. Thank you for comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's a feature of C++ called *undefined behavior*. You can't do pointer arithmetics outside an array (or one position over the bound of the array) you own.

You could get this to work by `a += 1` because `a` is already a `int*`, so `+= 1` will make it point to the next integer. `a+=sizeof(int)` will move it `sizeof(int)` integers to the right.

```
 +------+------+------+------+------+
 |      |      |      |      |      |      
 +------+------+------+------+------+
    ^      ^                    ^
    |      |                    |
    a     a+1               a+sizeof(int) (assuming sizeof(int) == 4)
```

Again, technically it's undefined.

Comment: @Myosotis it's probably the address of `c` then.

Answer (score 7):

Well for starters I don't think pointer arithmetic works how you think it works. You do not need to do `sizeof(int)`, because the pointer is already a pointer to `int`, so the compiler knows that `a++` will need to advance 4 bytes.

Secondly no, you can't point to local variables as you have no idea where the compiler has placed them in memory, their lifetime, or even if they are in memory at all. The compiler will optimise many local variables into CPU registers.

EDIT: Yes, as per valid comments I should clarify that you can take pointers to local variables, and the compiler will do the right thing, but you cannot use pointer arithmetic with them since they may be optimised away completely.

Comment: The second part is a bit misleading. It's perfectly acceptable to take the address of local variables, but this kind of pointer arithmetic is meaningless (although you can do pointer arithmetic within local arrays of course).

Comment: Not only misleading, it's completely wrong. Of course you can take the addresses of locals and point to them.

Comment: Optimizations can't affect observed behavior, so that's not a valid reason for not being able to do pointer arithmetic on them. The reason is that the standard disallows it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't assume that all the variables are aligned the way you want it, and you can't use pointer arithmetics in this way. The only way to use it safely is to use it inside the bounds of an array of yours. Also, `a+=sizeof(int)` doesn't move it to point to the next integer, but moves it by `sizeof(int)` integers.

You are relying on UB here, thus you can not expect any particular result. Actually you may even get a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

No its not Visual Studio 2010 feature. Arithmetic operations for pointers shows undefined behaviour.

Normally, only use increment/decrement when pointing to elements of an array

Comment: What do you mean "You can't trust on arithmetic operations for pointers"?